# Element type is invalid when i wrap my app with <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I get an error when i try wrapping my `<App>` with `<Provder>`, here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import reducer from './store/reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Here is the error i get after i use `<Provider>`:
[image]

And here is my `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "react-complete-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

In the end i realize this is probably related to a conflict of version in my `package.json`, but now matter how much i update each package i can't fix this, i also tried common fixes suggested in other threads with a similar problem but still no luck.
Thanks.

**Update 01 :**
`App.js :`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Counter from './containers/Counter/Counter';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <Counter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your App.js code? If no, you should include the way you define and export it.

Comment: @MikhailLitvinov Since the project is very small, i added the whole `app.js` to the post